# Error a la hora de implementar pruebas unitarias en React Native con Reactnavigation

Tags: react-native, test, pruebas-unitarias, react-navigation

Estoy teniendo el siguiente problema:

> Invariant Violation: Native module cannot be null.
>
> ```
>   at invariant (node_modules/fbjs/lib/invariant.js:42:15)
>   at new NativeEventEmitter (node_modules/react-native/Libraries/EventEmitter/NativeEventEmitter.js:35:7)
>   at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-native-google-analytics-bridge/src/Helpers/FunctionCallTagHandler/index.io
> ```
>
> s.js:16:37)
>         at Object. (node_modules/react-native-google-analytics-bridge/src/GoogleTagManager.js:2:1)

Estoy tratando de *testear* el *login* de una app, de la cual tiene el componente raíz, del cual verifica el estado y dependiendo si esta *logueado* o no abre el *login* o la pantalla principal del usuario.
¿Alguien sabría como solucionarlo?

Comment: por que no usas mejor RouterFlux

Comment: No es mio el codigo, proponer cambio y que me lo aprueben, tardaria mucho

Comment: puedes ver este post https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/2977, tal parece que tu problema se debe a que falta la libreria RCTLinking

Answer (score 0):

La solución me la dieron desde stack overflow en ingles el usuario

y consiste en modificar el package.json en la parte de jest, dejandolo de la siguiente manera:

```
"jest": {
        "preset": "react-native",
        "haste": {
          "defaultPlatform": "android",
          "platforms": [
            "android",
            "ios"
          ],
          "providesModuleNodeModules": [
            "react",
            "react-native",
            "react-native-push-notification"
          ]
        },
        "collectCoverageFrom": [
            "src/**/*.js"
        ],
        "coverageReporters": [
            "html",
            "text"
        ],
        "transformIgnorePatterns": [
            "node_modules/(?!(jest-)?react-native|react-navigation)"
        ],
        "setupFiles": [
            "<rootDir>/__mock__/pushNotificationIOS.js"
        ]
      }
```

y crear en la raiz del proyecto una carpeta llamada `__mock__` que contendría al archivo `pushNotificationIOS.js` con el siguiente código:

```
const PushNotificationIOSMock = jest.mock('react-native-push-notification', () => ({
    configure: jest.fn(),
    onRegister: jest.fn(),
    onNotification: jest.fn(),
    addEventListener: jest.fn(),
    requestPermissions: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve()),
    getInitialNotification: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve()),
}));

global.PushNotificationIOS = PushNotificationIOSMock;
```

y en el archivo del test importar

```
import {GoogleAnalyticsTracker} from 'react-native-google-analytics-bridge';

jest.mock('react-native-google-analytics-bridge');
```